# Are there any non-humanoid elves?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, elf

Is there any race which, without applying any external option (e.g. feat, template, spell),

- qualifies as an elf for prerequisites (read: is named as some kind of elf, has the elf subtype, and/or has something like half-elves’ elven blood allowing the race to qualify), and
- is not humanoid (read: has one of the other creature types)?

Official material (WotC-published or WotC-approved, e.g. *Dragon*, *Dungeon*, *Oriental Adventures*) only. Templates not allowed even if printed that way (e.g. if someone wrote an article about half-dragon elves and wrote up racial stats for them with the half-dragon template baked in, that doesn’t count—but a draconic elf that isn’t made from a template could work). LA +0 races vastly preferred.

Comment: While they don't qualify, I'd expect driders to fit that - but their description rules doesn't reflect their elven history in any way...

Comment: @G0BLiN Great thought, though I suppose it does kind of make sense that Lolth’s punishment would twist drow so much that they are no longer even elves anymore.

Comment: Can you tell readers *why* the creature needs to count as an elf yet *not* be a humanoid?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The prompt was the fangshields ranger substitution level and Aerenal Beastmaster feat, for a total of +5 to effective animal companion level; I could definitely do both with templates but I was curious if there were any non-template options. And the idea of a more monstrous elf seemed interesting and I wanted to see what if anything Wizards had done with the concept.

Comment: I feel it necessary to point out (for posterity) that, unlike often mistakenly believed, the Prestige Class Ruathar does NOT in fact give the character the ability to count as elf. It merely gives them a bunch of elf-like traits.

Comment: @WeckarE. An excellent point, and well made. I often forget that myself. You could argue, though, that you could claim the ruathar to be an implementation of the stoneblessed adaptation suggested by *Races of Stone*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## The [celadrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celadrin) should work…

The *Dragon* #350 article "Legacies of Ancient Empires" (50-7) by Eric Boyd describes the **celadrin** planetouched. They possess the type outsider and the subtype native, have Level Adjustment +1 and no racial Hit Dice, and possess, among other abilities, the racial trait elven blood:

> For all special abilities and effects related to race, a celadrin is considered an elf. Celadrins, for example, can use elven weapons and magic items with racially specific elven powers as if they were elves.  (52)

While this description of the racial trait elven blood is *slightly* different from the description found in the *Player's Handbook* and *Monster Manual* for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*, it nonetheless aligns *perfectly* (with appropriate finding-and-replacing, obviously) with the half-elf racial trait elven blood from the *Player's Handbook* for *Dungeons and Dragons, Third Edition*! Despite *Dragon* magazine having converted to *3.5e* over *forty* issues earlier, with such evidence in hand, it should be a small matter to convince the DM to make a minor adjustment that will bring this outdated *Third Edition* description of the racial trait elven blood up to *3.5e* standards.

### …And so should the [fey'ri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetouched#Daemonfey)…

The planetouched **fey'ri** (*Races of Faerûn* 118-21) possess the type outsider and the subtype native, have Level Adjustment +2 (or +3 with damage reduction or the spell-like ability *dimension door* or *enervation*) and no racial Hit Dice, and possess, among other abilities, the racial trait elven blood like the aforementioned celadrin and other pre-*3.5* revision elflike creatures (hence making some minor adjustments by the DM a necessity).

The *Player's Guide to Faerûn* Web enhancement ["Monster Update"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20040313a) mentions in passing that fey'ri are *also* tieflings (5). This allows a fey'ri to, for example, meet requirements and feat prerequisites it couldn't've met as *just* a planetouched fey'ri. That is, a generous DM may allow such a fey'ri to enter the class [tiefling paragon](http://dndsrd.net/unearthedParagon.html#tiefling-paragon-races) (*UA* 45-6) (for all the good it'll do the fey'ri) or take a feat like Planetouched Animal Affinity (*Races of Faerûn* 167) (for all the good *that* feat does *anyone*).

(A player can ask the DM if this also means that a fey'ri gets, *in addition* to the typical traits of a fey'ri, the traits of the typical tiefling (*Monster Manual* 209-10). The DM will probably say *No*, but a player *can* ask, and, really, LA +2 is *a lot*. But, here, just in case, take this helmet, and look out for hurled dice.)

#### …but other creatures will struggle

While the *Epic Level Handbook* belabors the creature's closeness to elves, the [leShay](http://dndsrd.net/epicNonAbominations.html#leshay) (202-3), an epic fey with 50 Hit Dice and no supplied Level Adjustment, has the natural ability elf traits that does *not* seem to enable a leShay to meet elven blood requirements and prerequisites, instead only providing the leShay with minor elf-like features *without* it actually being an elf. However, with a leShay's *fifty [fey](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#fey) racial Hit Dice*, this DM would seriously consider a house rule granting a leShay the racial trait elven blood. At the typical point at which a leShay is usable as a PC, that's *not* going to be a big deal.

Keith Baker's Web article ["Druids of Khorvaire, Part Four"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebds/20051114a) includes the description of the **Valenar warhorse**, an animal with 4 Hit Dice, no supplied Level Adjustment, and an Intelligence score of 2 (and, according to *Dungeon Master's Guide* 172, the DM should not "allow players to play creatures who have an Intelligence score of 2 or lower"). Nonetheless, if the DM is accommodating (maybe the Valenar warhorse is the subject of an [*awaken*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#awaken) effect?), the section Valenar Horses says

> Aside from its enhanced speed and Dexterity, a Valenar horse can live for up to ten times the lifespan of a normal horse; **the Tairnadal [elves] attribute this longevity to the elven blood they believe runs through the veins of the steed**.

(Emphasis mine.) Ask the DM if this belief is true then, if it is, ask if it means a Valenar horse technically meets prerequisites and requirements as if the horse has the racial trait elven blood. (Were this DM to approve such a thing, he would concoct a tale that has an injured Valenar horse in the distant past receiving a field transfusion from his elven master. So you know.)

---

***Note:*** I made a good faith effort to work my way through this edition's printed Wizards of the Coast material as well as Web material. I did not *search extensively issues of* Dragon, Dungeon, Living Greyhawk Journal, *or* Polyhedron *nor third party material that bears the officially approved Wizards of the Coast seal. Other options may yet exist, buried in more obscure sources.*

Comment: @KRyan The question interested me. A campaign I'm running now is based on the U. S. Revolutionary War but substitutes elves for the British, so knowing what things count as elves is useful to me, too.

Comment: Exemplary answer, as ever. Are you likely to write up notes on the revolutionary campaign? It sounds very worth stealing...

Comment: The Valenar Elf Horses are believed to be descended from druids who were trapped in Wild Shape form by powerful magic.  This may or may not make things better from your perspective.

Answer (score 12):

The only non-humanoid elf race I know of are the **Fey'ri** (*Races of Faerun*, p. 118), who are Outsiders that count as elves due to the *Elven Blood* racial feature.  Unfortunately, they're LA +2.

A perusal of [all](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=1281.0) [the](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=f8m28hucn4a7iqbcgonaurkoa3&topic=342.0) [lists](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?484406-All-Elf-subraces) turned up by Google doesn't yield any other promising results, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Great answer, I really appreciate you showing your work and letting me know what has already been checked.

Comment: Leshay (from the epic level handbook) may or may not count too. They are Fey, but their fluff talks about elves, and they have the ability "elf traits".

Comment: The Elf Traits feature doesn't mention anything about counting as elves for prereq purposes, and they don't have a listed LA (for obvious reasons related to their 50 HD).  I feel pretty okay about leaving them off this answer.